# Static TableViewControllers cells UI don't show up when connected to a controller

Tags: uitableview, ios8, xcode6

I am running into a strange problem regarding Uitableview cells in Xcode 6 iOS8. When I create a tableViewController from storyboard and choose static cells, the view shows up as it suppose to. However, when I connect that same view to a TableViewController source, the cells disappear. I connected all necessary things (reusable cell_ID, etc). Anyone experience this? This used to work for me previously.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Woops. I forgot `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:`

Comment: That also did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you don't implement any of `UITableViewDatasourceDelegate` methods in your `TableViewController` such as these methods below.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```